# Conditional formatting for three previous columns from column which has TRUE

Tags: excel, excel-formula, multiple-columns, conditional-formatting

I have a sheet which has 21 shifts in columns D:X. Just one shift at a time is TRUE, others are FALSE. How I can use conditional formatting so every time the TRUE moves ahead according to other rules, three previous shifts before TRUE are highlighted?

I know how to use conditional formatting to columns, but just the formula makes pain. I think it is quite easy one, but I do not know all excel formulas very well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use following formula in conditional formatting:

```
=OR(INDEX(D2:G2,1,N(IF(1,ROW($A$1:$A$3)+1))))
```

Apply formatting to range `D2:X2` or adjust accordingly.

[image]

Comment: This works great! I know OR, INDEX and ROW functions and how they behave as excel sheet formulas. Never used N function but checked it too and it is easy one. But still I wonder how this OR behaves in this conditional formatting, because there is not other part of OR like OR(A1,A2). A2 is missing in that formula, I do not understand, please help with some clarification. And what that "1" makes in IF formula?

Comment: Tried to clarify how "N", "IF" and "ROW" functions work as dummy functions on an excel sheet and the outcome is that just "ROW" function gives the same table (2,3,4 in one column) as all three functions together. But above conditional formatting does not work without "N" and "IF" functions. Could you clarify just this? OR function is clear now, found "Truth table"

Comment: Well, I'll try to explain the whole formula. ```ROW($A$1:$A$3)+1)``` returns a array of constant numbers ```{2,3,4}```. In principle, this kind of notation can be used in the worksheet formula, but excel does not allow it in conditional formatting, so it can be tricked with the ```ROW``` function. ```N(IF(1,...``` is required to force ```INDEX``` to return multiple items to ```OR``` function, otherwise ```INDEX``` will return only the first value. ```INDEX(D2:G2,1,{2,3,4})``` returns from range ```D2:G2``` values of the last three columns, while ```OR``` checks these three values.

Comment: Thank you very much, now it is clear. There is really some trickies needed like ROW and N(IF(1,,,